# Get the date a repo was created

Tags: libgit2

What is the way to get the date a repo was created using libgit2 library?
My initial idea was to get the first commit from a master branch and check its time but I'm not sure if there are better/more straightforward ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems right, but the answer also depends on what you mean by "date a repo was created".

For example, I *could* create an empty repo with `git init` and then forget about it for a while and make my first commit a year later. Personally, I don't think that year when nothing was done with the repo is important and I would use the date of the first commit.

If, on the other hand, you think that year important, then you could try using the filesystem commands (sorry, not sure what language you're using) to get file creation dates from the `.git` directory or some file inside that directory.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, and indeed, .git folder's date is the date I'm interested in. Best regards. Will accept as soon as I can.